# How I can search a phone number from the database regardless of how they are stored or searched?

Tags: php, mysql

**The problem is searching with both country code and without country code:**

1. If the phone number stored in the db is without country code (ex: 0914093949), it must be found when searched with country code (+251914093949) or viceversa
2. If the phone number stored in the db is with country code (ex: +251914093949), it must be found when it searched with without country code (ex:0914093949) and viceversa

I tried the following code:

```
 SELECT trainee.*, organization.organization AS orgName, course.course_name AS courseName
        FROM trainee
        LEFT JOIN organization ON trainee.organization = organization.organ_id
        LEFT JOIN course ON trainee.course = course.id
        WHERE firstName = ? OR lastName = ? OR trainee.email = ?
        OR trainee.phone = ? OR trainee.phone = CONCAT('+251', ?)
    ");
```

The above works for only phone registered with country code in my case for ex. +251914093949. But didn't work for numbers registered with without country code and searching them by with cuuntry code!

Comment: Can we take one step back? What problem are you trying to solve? In other words: Why do you need to search for a phone number? Usually it is the other way around: You look up a phone number given some other detail, like a name.

Comment: Normalise to international format before storing and always search using international format.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Phone number is required and more unique than others

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to validate input? Isn't an email address unique enough? Your explanation doesn't clarify much. It will be very difficult to help you without knowing what you're trying to achieve. Lack of context also got your question closed. Is [the mentioned duplicate Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873/searching-for-phone-numbers-in-mysql) useful to you?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware In my system, phone is more unique than email because email might not be registered in the system, but phone is required and mandatory! That's why I used phone number to search exisiting trainee!!

Comment: OK. One tip: You might want to look into the MySQL `LIKE` operator. It allows you to find trainees using only parts of a name or phone number. See: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_like.asp

Comment: Matches that require LIKE/REGEXP/string functions/etc will not be able to use indexes. If you canonicalize the phone numbers to a single representation, as user1191247 suggested, you can look them up efficiently with indexes.

Comment: I haven't understood you @Sammitch ... I did the following and it worked.
.
.
.
 ...trainee.phone = ? 
    OR CONCAT('+251', trainee.phone) = ? 
    OR trainee.phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    OR CONCAT('+251', trainee.phone) LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')

I don't think this will have a problem in the future

Comment: [Indexes can make queries a lot faster](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm), when you can make use of them. Even if a query has a column with an index it often cannot use it effectively if the query uses LIKE/REGEXP/string functions/etc. This becomes important when you use large data sets. For more details see: [Use the index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning). Nobody ever said that understanding databases would be easy. 